# atof() returns 3 digit number into 2 digits

Tags: floating-point, arduino, atof

I am trying to parse a string sent to my arduino uno using serial communication into a float. I want to use these floats to set an RGB LED's color. My issue is, it will only read the first 2 digits. Sorta. Say I entered 100. It will only come out to 10.00. If it's 231, it will come out to 23.00. The weird thing is, if I put 32.43, it will come out 32.4300.  I have no idea why it does this. Here is my code:

```
float led1Color[3];

...

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int index = content.indexOf(",");
    content = content.substring(index + 1); //removes additional text in front of numbers
    led1Color[i] = atof(content.substring(0, index).c_str());
    Serial.println(led1Color[i], 4);
}
```

Now lets say I sent the following: "RGBLED,43.61,52,231". First, the RGBLED is removed. Then, the 3 values the console shows me are as followed:

> 43.6100
>   52.0000
>   23.0000

Obviously the issue here is I need the value 231, not 23.0000. I've never actually programmed in C/C++ before, so is there something I'm missing? Why is a three digit number being converted into a two digit number?

Comment: This code looks like C++, not C.

Comment: My apologies. I'm not fluent in either. I'll change the tags.

Comment: Have you verified the contents of `content`?

Comment: It seems this is not an issue with atof() but rather with the string. I logged content.substring(0, index).c_str() and it returned only the two digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is the value of index.
This finds the first comma correctly

```
int index = content.indexOf(",");
```

But this second substring uses the same value of index from the previous find:

```
... content.substring(0, index).c_str()  // ERROR - index is the last value
```

So when the string is reduced to:

```
content -> "52,231"
```

index returns **2**

Then you chop of to the comma and have

```
content -> "231"
```

The code takes 2 characters from that which gives you 23.

If you change the input to

```
"RGBLED,43.61,5,231"
```

You would get "2" for the last atof.

If you change the input to

```
"RGBLED,43.61,52.,231"
```

You would get "231" for the last atof.

The approach you take of reducing the string is not necessary.  indexOf takes a second parameter that can specify the starting point.

This code is on your way to a better solution because you don't use memory to keep re-assigning the content string -- it just finds the commas and processes the sections:

```
index1 = content.indexOf(",");
index2 = content.indexOf("," , index1+1);
index3 = content.indexOf("," , index2+1);

led1Color[0] = atof(content.substring(index1+1, index2).c_str());
led1Color[1] = atof(content.substring(index2+1, index3).c_str());
led1Color[2] = atof(content.substring(index3+1).c_str());
```